# Breeze: Filtering by Date only on a DateTime type

Tags: odata, breeze

I'm passing in the following Predicate into an EntityQuery but no results are being returned even tho I have data for the specified date:

```
// query equals 'Wed Feb 05 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)'
Predicate.create('createdDateTime', '==', query);
```

This creates the following query in oData:

```
$filter=CreatedDateTime%20eq%20datetime%272014-02-05T00%3A00%3A00.000Z%27
```

The data held in the database also has the time value: `2014-02-05 14:18:02.590`, so I guess this is why no data is returned? So my question is, how can I filter just on the Date value, ignoring the time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DateTime queries are tricky ***everywhere*** particularly when you consider that server time and client time are often unaligned. Time zone considerations can lead to madness. It's not really a Breeze problem *per se*.

With those caveats in mind, consider how best to bracket the date you care about (with greaterThan/lessThan) logic. It gets vastly easier if you eliminate the time component altogether by storing some kind of normalized date-only value in UTC. Wish I knew a better answer.

Comment: Hi Ward, I actually managed to solve it, somewhat un-elegantly by using the following: `predicate.and('createdDateTime', '>', queryDate).and('createdDateTime', '<', moment(queryDate).add('days', 1));`